# Flutter Amplify S3 Guest Access

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to swap S3 buckets used by my app and having problems with access errors. To test what is possible I created a new bucket from the Amplify CLI (it works), removed it, then reloaded it. I would have expected this to work - but once reloaded I get a 403 access error. What do I need to change/add to reinstate guest access?

These are the steps I took:

From the Amplify CLI

amplify add storage

to create a new bucket. I give guest user all CRUD rights. I can upload to this with

Future uploadFileWithAmplify() async {
File file = File(feedbackMedia.localMediaId!);

```
// Upload the file to S3
try {
  final UploadFileResult result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
      local: file,
      key: feedbackMedia.bucketPrefix + feedbackMedia.idMedia.toString() + feedbackMedia.fileExtension,
      options: S3UploadFileOptions(
        accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.guest,
      ),
      onProgress: (progress) {
        print('Fraction completed: ${progress.getFractionCompleted()}');
      },
    // options:
  );
    print('Successfully uploaded file: ${result.key}');
    return true;
} on StorageException catch (e) {
    print('Error uploading file: $e');
    return false;
}
```

}

without a problem

At the CLI I enter

amplify remove storage

and say yes to
? Are you sure you want to delete the resource? This action deletes all files related to this resource from the backend directory. (Y/n) y

then
amplify push

Then
amplify import storage
And I choose the same bucket
amplify push

The upload no longer works I get a 403 error

Error uploading file: StorageException(message: Something went wrong with your AWS S3 Storage upload file operation, recoverySuggestion: See attached exception for more information and suggestions, underlyingException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
I/flutter ( 8670): `AccessDenied`Access Denied3PC2F2D14ZWMQAVSsvIuDBzLgFdwA88cA8DWfxYu7eGmoFAp6925MFmy6XIQUZg/f0mf/sCzQ1Nqw4sFxtCun3CF/6glEhf8Y07kcQ== (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: 3PC2F2D14ZWMQAVS), S3 Extended Request ID:

Something must have changed in remove that doesn't get reinstated on import - but I don't know what.